# Devising measure of vertical distance from spring line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

I am building a model (using Logistic Regression) to explore the relation between a binary categorical dependent variable (parcels agricultural production quality) and several predictors, among which slope, curvature, distance from the coastline, etc.

One of the predictors I wish to include in the model (the significance of its contribution pending) is distance from spring line. I have digitized the spring line as a polyline.

The spring line is usually rather high in elevation (in the territory under study) and it lies where two geological layers meet up.

Now, I would like to devise a distance measure which allows to discriminate between areas below the spring line and above it.

The rationale of it would be that, due to gravity, areas (and related parcels) above the spring line could possibly be more difficult to irrigate, whereas areas (and related parcels) below the spring line would be easier to irrigate.

I hope my poor English manages to make my point.

Comment: I suppose the spring line is not a constant elevation? I don't have specific steps, but I'm thinking some DEM manipulation would get the raster you're after. For example determining the line elevation then reclassifying so that elevation becomes 0 and all other cells then are positive/negative values moving away. Without constant elevation that becomes more difficult, but I'm sure there's a way. If you just want a binary higher/lower than spring line raster, that would be easier. Something in Spatial Analyst should be able to solve this.

Comment: @Chris W: thank you for the suggestion. I think I could calculate the mean elevation of the spring lines and evaluate how much variability (i.e., standard deviation and/or coefficient of variation) is there. If it is not too much, I could put your suggested approach at work. On this respect, could you elaborate a bit more on how the procedure would be to reclassify the dem in order to set the mean elevation to zero, and the other values to be positive/negative? Thank you

Comment: That would be a simple [raster calculation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000). Assuming a mean or constant spring line elevation, you'd just take the DEM as input and subtract that elevation value from it (meaning every cell minus that value). The resulting raster would then zero out at the desired elevation with postive values for anything over it and negative values for anything below - essentially a difference raster between the DEM and one of constant value.

Comment: @Chris W: I see, thank you. Unfortunately, as you envisaged, the springline has not a equal elevation. I have attempted to devise a sort of robust z-score, subtracting the Median springline elevation from the DEM, and dividing by the Median Absolute Deviation. Thank you again.